# error in using tab in makefile how to fix it

Tags: makefile

when I try to do make for the makefile it shows me (makefile error missing separator. stop)
my make file is

```
PROGS = $(patsubst %.c,%,$(SRCS))
all: $(PROGS)
%: %.c
      arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc --static $< -o $@
clean:
      rm -f $(PROGS)
```

I try to use the following command but I could not solve my problem
`cat -e -t -v Makefile`

````
SRCS^I=^I$(wildcard^I*.c)^I$
PROGS^I=^I$(patsubst^I%.c,%,$(SRCS))$
all:^I$(PROGS)^I$
%:^I%.c^I$
      arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc^I--static^I$<^I-o^I$@^I$
clean:^I$
      rm^I-f^I$(PROGS)^I$ ```
````

Comment: Fix your text editor to not use spaces or soft tabs

Comment: Can I Fix my text editor in ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, you can. What problems are you having with it?

Answer (score 1):

Crazy.  You have TAB characters in *all* the places you *don't* need them, and you *don't* have TAB characters in *any* of the (two) places you *must* have them.  I don't know how you managed that.

In your makefile above the places you MUST have TAB chars are the recipe lines.  In other words, your makefile should look like this from `cat -e -t -v Makefile`:

```
SRCS = $(wildcard *.c)$
PROGS = $(patsubst %.c,%,$(SRCS))$
all: $(PROGS)$
%: %.c$
^Iarm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc --static $< -o $@$
clean:$
^Irm -f $(PROGS)$
```

As for configuring your text editor, there are a ton of text editors out there, even on Ubuntu, and we have no idea which one you are using.

I recommend you use a programmer's editor, which has a special mode that understands makefile syntax.